# Graphql and access to Types Properties depending on some logic

Tags: api, graphql

I am new to `Graphql` and some things still confuse me.

I am working on a project, similar to `Todo List`.
User may have multiple `todo items`, some of item's properties must be visible to owner only, some should be public.

So far I came up with two ideas:

1) First is to create two separate types, something like:

```
ToDoType {
    id
    name
    complete
}

ToDoPrivateType {
    id
    name
    complete
    colorGroup
    createdAt
    ...other private properties
}
```

And access
- ToDoType from root query `user {...}` and everywhere else, except
- `viewer {...}` where I will use ToDoPrivateType

It will work but looks a little like double-work,
plus if I retrieve `todo lists` from standard `user` root query I will not be able to pull private properties for user's own user.

2) I can also provide access to all properties and set to `null` properties to which a random user should not have access (like `createdAt` of other's users) but it also does not look right.

Hope what I am asking is not too confusing.

- Do these approaches make sense?
- Is there a better way to control access to some properties?

Thanks!